# Changing Name in Link Browser Typo3

Tags: typo3, typoscript

The Names I wanna change
[image: The Names I wanna change]

How do I change the Names of the marked Menus?

Comment: as you edited your question and removed important code from the question it is unclear why the answer matches. I assume there were names you want to remove from your question. for every question (and answer) make sure to anonymize to specific information like company names or domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably with different labels instead of using always the same:
`label = LLL:EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Language/Backend.xlf:browse_links.press`

Comment: open the file with an editor (plain text) and look at the XML structure. Now you should be able to identify your labels.

Comment: you need to add the entries in the XML file, then use that label in the Typoscript configuration. if you miss the new entries you need to clear the System-cache (maybe the clear cache in the install tool.